# How can I connect an AD-supported printer to a MySQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, active-directory

I am trying to connect a network-connected printer to a MySQL database - which is part of an ASP.NET C# application - to authenticate users.

The printer supports Active Directory for user authentication.

My idea was to create an ASP web service which internally authenticates the user just like when logging in the ASP application and intercepts the authentication requests from the printer.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

The printer (a Minolta c250) just supports active directory or NTLM for user authentication via external servers. I need an interface between that and the existing MySQL database.

Comment: My first thoughts are... wtf... connecting a network printer to a mysql database to auth users ?!?!?!? Surely theres a better way.... users are already authed because they logged in... so what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The thing is that i am very limited in my options. the printer only supports active directory or ntlm login (its a minolta c250) to authenticate users via a server. as i do not want to enter all the user data manually into the printer i want to fetch them from our server. we already have a online asp.net application with all the user data stored in a mysql database. i do not need to store or retrieve anything from that database, i just need to validate the username and password the user entered on the printer and give the printer a yes or no to unlock...

Comment: Not sure how to accomplish this apart from delving into http://www.konicaminolta.eu/en/business-solutions/services-solutions/developer-support-program/bizhub-extended-solution-technology.html ... good luck